# Slide Toggle | Abrir un solo div a la vez

Tags: html, jquery, slide

Estoy con un problema. Tengo varios divs colapsables, donde al hacer click en el titulo dse abren o se cierran. El problema es que al hacer click en uno de ellos, se abren todos los otros tambien, y lo mismo pasa al cerrarlos. Aqui el codigo:

HTML:

```
<a class="toggle-title"><p class="title_celeste">EN TRÁNSITO <i class="fa fa-angle-down font18"></i></p></a>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            CONTENIDO
        </div>

<a class="toggle-title"><p class="title_celeste">PORTERÍA <i class="fa fa-angle-down font18"></i></p></a>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            CONTENIDO
        </div>
        
<a class="toggle-title"><p class="title_celeste">CALADO <i class="fa fa-angle-down font18"></i></p></a>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            CONTENIDO
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle-title", function (evt) {
    $(this).parent().find('.toggle-content').slideToggle(600);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('rotate-toggle');
    return false;
});
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna forma de al hacer click abrir un solo div a la vez sin tener que agregar una clase particular para cada div?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En StackOverflow en inglés me dejaron la solución a este problema: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67539948/7724568